# Passing several arguments to single parameterized method with "|"?

Tags: java

I did some android stuff and found strange java code snippet.

I checked following with j2se and it gives commented results(without "prints").

Java code snippet looked like following:

```
class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(1 | 2); //prints 3
        method(1 | 2 | 3); //prints 3
        method(1 | 2 | 3 | 4);//prints 7
    }

    public static void method(int value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

My question is what is happening here?

Comment: That is bitwise OR operator, you need to brush up your basics

Comment: `I checked following with j2se` - "J2SE" ? :-)

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` is a bitwise-OR operator.

It's applying an OR to the numeric values. Easier to see in binary:

```
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4

 1 is 0...00000001 
 2 is 0...00000010
 3 is 0...00000011
 4 is 0...00000100
OR:   0...00000111  bitwise OR of all values
      0...00000111 = 7
```

It's not passing "multiple values", it's an arithmetic expression that evaluates to a single value.

However, it's frequently used to pass e.g. sets of "boolean" flags, where each flag is represented by a bit. For example:

```
 static final int FLAG_CRISPY = 1;  // 00000001 binary
 static final int FLAG_SMOKED = 2;  // 00000010 binary
 static final int FLAG_ENDLESS = 4; // 00000100 binary
```

Then you may have a method:

```
 void makeBacon (int flags) {
     if ((flags & FLAG_CRISPY) != 0) // bitwise AND to check for flag
         ... flag is set
     if ((flags & FLAG_SMOKED) != 0) // bitwise AND to check for flag
         ... flag is set
     if ((flags & FLAG_ENDLESS) != 0) // bitwise AND to check for flag
         ... flag is set
 }
```

And you can call it like:

```
 makeBacon(FLAG_SMOKED | FLAG_ENDLESS);
```

Defining flags like this is convenient because you can modify the set of flags as the program evolves without having to make any changes to the method interface. It's also sometimes useful to be able to encapsulate a large set of options in a single `int` (e.g. when storing data to a binary file or sending over a network).

The [official tutorial on bitwise and bit-shift operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) has more information about other related operators (e.g. AND, XOR, left shift, right shift).

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise OR

```
1 | 2 = '01' | '10' = 11 = 3
1 | 2 | 3 = '01' | '10' | '11' =  11 = 3
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 = '01' | '10' | '11' | '100' = 111 = 7
```